# how to construct Dispose method in child class?

Tags: c#

I  have a child class like this :

```
SyncTelemetryChannel : ITelemetryChannel 
ITelemetryChannel : IDisposeable
```

What should i put in the SyncTelemetryChannel Dispose method ? Currently i have this:

```
public void Dispose() {}
```

Thanks,Peter

Comment: `ITelemetryChannel` is an interface?  (Double checking)

Comment: You should put a correct implementation of the dispose pattern. Does your object take ownership of unmanaged resources?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SyncTelemetryChannel : ITelemetryChannel
{
        private bool _disposed = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Releases unmanaged and - optionally - managed resources.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing"><c>true</c> to release both managed and unmanaged resources; <c>false</c> to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {                    
                // Free any other managed objects here.                    
            }

            // Free any unmanaged objects here.
            _disposed = true;
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks LP13 and Eric. I was over-thinking, and your comments helped me .